# Common / centralized method to handle multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception

**This is on Java 6**

Can I have a common method to handle my exceptions - so instead of doing this n times in each method

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (XException e) {
    // Do something
} catch (YException e) {
    // Do something
} catch (ZException e) {
    // Do something
}
```

I have

```
try {
        // Do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleAll (e);
    }
```

and method `handleAll(e)` does

```
if e.instanceOf(XException)

else if e.instanceOf(YException)

else if e.instanceOf(ZException)
```

Is there anything wrong with the 2nd approach?

**Update:**

My original question was about "centralizing the handling" in one place for both checked and runtime exceptions. The answers have pointed out I should avoid instanceof().

@aioobe's idea looks very neat to me. Are there any negative opinions on that approach?

Comment: What are you going to do with exceptions which don't fall into one of those three categories?

Comment: though all the exception handling doing same, its a bad practice to do this way. U can get rid of this in jdk 7

Comment: @Jon: Those 3 were only examples and end with a block for Exception

Comment: @shinynewbike: And what would that block do? That's the problem - either it's got to throw Exception, in which case you calling method *also* has to be declared to throw Exception, or it's got to swallow it, or wrap it in a RuntimeException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one minor problem as I see it. Since you really want the `handleAll` method to rethrow any uncaught exception, it has to be declared `throws Exception`. This means that so does the methods that call `handleAll`.

If `X-`, `Y-` and `ZException` are all `RuntimeExceptions` I see nothing wrong with this. (I may have overlooked something though, as this is the first time I've seen this approach.)

To be sure that the `instanceof` approach behaves exactly as the catch clauses would, I would consider designing the `handleAll(RuntimeException e)` like this though:

```
private void handleAll(RuntimeException e) {
    try {
        throw e;
    } catch (XException xe) {
        ...
    } catch (YException xe) {
        ...
    } catch (ZException xe) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: well actually these are a mix of Checked and Runtime

Comment: Then I suspect that you need `throws Exception` on the original method or yet another try / catch block around the call to handleAll, (or, worst of all, suppress uncaught exceptions in the handleAll method). In either case, it starts getting messy, and I would strongly consider replicating parts of the catch-clauses.

Answer (score 2):

It's a BAD approach. It will reduce LOC (Line Of Code) but it will create difficult to understand, More resource dependent (It requires more memory and processing capacity). it also reduce Readability.

So first one is the best one

Comment: On the other hand the first approach violates the DRY principle. To be honest, I don't think the `handleAll` approach reduces readability that much...

Comment: everything that involves instanceof is 99% bad practice.

Comment: instanceof can be avoided with the formulation I propose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but I don't think it's good coding style. It's convenient to keep exception handlers close to the lines that throw the Exceptions.
Suppose your code changes, and throws a new Exception. Then you have to update the method that handles them; so now you have to make changes in two places. Same happens if a particular Exception is no longer thrown by the code, or if you decide that some Exceptions should be handled at a higher level.

Also, I'm wary of "catch (Exception exc)". It's too general, try to make your Exception handlers as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 will make things better. Because [catching multiple exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is something really wrong with the second approach: if the called method signature is modified and throws a new kind of exception, the code will still compile fine, whereas you have not handled this new exception correctly.

Using the first approach, the compiler will produce an error, which will force you to handle the new exception.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Are you talking about checked exceptions?

Comment: Yes. catch(Exception) will catch the new exception type, and will pass it to handleAll, where it will be handled as an unknown exception. This will be discovered at runtime, rather than compile-time.

Comment: Right. Would you say the approach is ok if X-, Y- and ZException are all RuntimeExceptions, and the handleAll rethrows any uncaught exception?

Comment: RuntimeExceptions should rarely be caught anyway, so I'm not sure the question makes much sense. If the runtime exceptions must often be caught, maybe they should be checked exceptions. I would still prefer the standard (or new muti-catch) block.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will catch all `Exception`s, including `RunTimeException`s. Make sure you handle them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think every exception is unique (when compararized place in code, not the time when exception is thrown) so you should not generilaze exception handling.

You might want to handle exception little difference each time IE. if some where is thrown FileNotFoundException you might create a new file but other time that might be fatal Exception that causes applications termination.